# How to set up Jekyll collection archive URL?

Tags: url, jekyll

I use Jekyll to generate site with blog and custom collection named photos. My custom collection item has the following URL: 0.0.0.0:4000/photos/photo-name.

```
collections:
  photos:
    output: true
    permalink: /photos/:path/
```

In the _site directory they generating as:

```
_site/
  photos/
    photo-name/
      index.html
    other-photo-name/
      index.html
```

Now I'd like to have photos archive with the URL like this: 0.0.0.0:4000/photos/.

So is there a way to generate index.html in the _site/photos/ directory? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make an index page for your photos, just create a `photos.html` page with a `permalink : /photos/` in the front matter, it will generate a `_site/photos/index.html` page.